# Extraer parte numérica en campo alfanumérico

Tags: sql, sql-server

En la empresa con la que trabajo tenemos BD en SQL SERVER, a su vez, en la tabla `T_GLPERIODBAL` se registran las cuentas contables en un campo llamado `SegValue1` de 50 caracteres.

Necesito extraer los seis primeros caracteres de la cuenta contable. 
Generalmente los códigos de cuentas contables son de 9 caracteres numéricos, pero guardados en campos alfanuméricos como el campo `SegValue1`.

Cuando ejecuto el siguiente select:

```
SELECT SegValue1  FROM T_GLPERIODBAL
```

El sistema muestra el campo `SegValue1` justificado a la derecha (como campo numérico).

Al ejecutar el select:

```
SELECT CAST(SegValue1 AS CHAR(6)) FROM T_GLPERIODBAL
```

Genera el siguiente mensaje de error:

> “Error de desbordamiento aritmético para el tipo varchar, valor = 110510001.000000.”.

Por lo anterior, acudo a la ayuda de la comunidad. Gracias.

Comment: Edita tu título, mayúsculas == gritar. Gracias :)

Answer (score 2):

Si lo que necesitas son los 6 primeros números del campo de texto, puedes hacerlo con la función `LEFT`.

```
SELECT LEFT(SegValue1, 6) as SegValue1
FROM T_GLPERIODBAL
```

Si el contenido del campo `SegValue1` contiene puntos, deberás hacer un `REPLACE` para eliminarlos

```
SELECT LEFT(REPLACE(SegValue1, '.', ''), 6) as SegValue1
FROM T_GLPERIODBAL
```

Comment: Gracias Roger. Al hacer como sugiere, con LEFT, inserta un punto así: 1.1051 para la cuenta 110510001; 1.1100 para la cuenta 111005001 y así sucesivamente.

Comment: La función `LEFT` no pone ningún carácter, solo toma los primeros dígitos. Si aparecen puntos, es que el campo contiene puntos. Para solucionarlo puedes hacer un `REPLACE`, tal como he puesto en la respuesta editada.

Comment: <! -- language: lang-sql -->